# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Error using linqtextquerybuilder

Tags: c#, .net, linq

To my surprise it's not working!! I used `linqtextquerybuilder` in my code but, I'm confused.  Here is my code but I don't know how to fix error:

```
var source = file.AsQueryable();
LinqTextQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new LinqTextQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.SetSource(source);
string queryText = @"from  f in source select new {  f.Authors,  f.EnglishTitle, f.journal }";

var result =  queryBuilder.Query(queryText);  //but this query itsself worked!!

var result2 =  from  f in source select new {  f.Authors,  f.EnglishTitle, f.journal };
```

I got the following error at: `var result =  queryBuilder.Query(queryText);`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What's the problem?

Comment: What is file? Did you check if it is null?

Comment: What is the stack trace?  if `source` is not null (and that really is the line that's throwing the error) then something inside `LinqTextQueryBuilder.SetSource` is throwing the error and you may need to ask the authors what is throwing the error.

Comment: @Steve: no file is a list and isn't null

Comment: @DStanley: I mentioned it above.
var result2 =  from  f in source select new {  f.Authors,  f.EnglishTitle, f.journal }; works and source isn't null!!

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://linqtextquerybuilder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/LinqTextQueryBuilder.cs), the only way this could throw that exception is if file is null or not instantiated. Please provide more code.

Comment: @DionV. If `file` were null the exception would have come from the `file.AsQueryable();` call.

Comment: @user3915488 I'm confused - you can an exception is thrown at line 2 of your snippet but that line 6 "works"?  How is that possible?

Comment: @DStanley you're right, I meant 'source' not 'file'.

Comment: @DStanley : yeah the problem is this!!
the query itself is right and works bur when I copy it as var queryText I expect the linqtextquerybuilder run it well,but I can't understand what happens.

Comment: consider that
 var result2 =  from  f in source select new {  f.Authors,  f.EnglishTitle, f.journal };
is just a query not string and irrelevant to linqtextquerybuilder